# OpenIDM - AD Users REST API

Tags: openidm

I'm new to openIDM, I'm trying to execute the following query, getting zero results, though I have lot of AD users exist, just wondering what I'm doing wrong,

$ curl \

--header "X-OpenIDM-Username: openidm-admin" \
 --header "X-OpenIDM-Password: openidm-admin" \
 "https://localhost:8443/openidm/managed/user?_queryId=query-all-ids"

Results:

{"query-time-ms":0,"result":[],"conversion-time-ms":0}

But it works for Groups

$ curl \

--header "X-OpenIDM-Username: openidm-admin" \
 --header "X-OpenIDM-Password: openidm-admin" \
 "https://localhost:8443/openidm/managed/group?_queryId=query-all-ids"

Thanks

Comment: Have you defined a connector for your AD accounts? Have you created a mapping between that connector and managed/user? Have you executed recon for that mapping?

Comment: Thanks I haven't configured it, once after config changes, I'm able to sync AD users.

Comment: You are allowed to provide an answer to your own question. Please describe how you got it working as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify Sync.json file, to add user related information like showing in the following link, http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openidm/3.1.0/integrators-guide/index/chap-synchronization.html#synchronization-mappings-file

My config looks like,

{
    "name" : "managedUser_systemLdapAccounts",
    "source" : "System/AD/Account",
    "target" : "managed/user",
    ...
}

Executed the recon job as mentioned in same doc,

$ curl \
 --cacert self-signed.crt \
 --header "X-OpenIDM-Username: openidm-admin" \
 --header "X-OpenIDM-Password: openidm-admin" \
 --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
 --request POST \
 "https://localhost:8443/openidm/recon?_action=recon&mapping=systemLdapAccounts_managedUser"

Also, I added routes in Managed.JSON {"name", "user"}, {"name", "account"}, though I see this doesn't matter much, when you execute a managed object query, you can choose any endpoints defined in this file and execute a different query not related to the endpoint it still works.

Thanks